# Proving a set is uncountable using $(0,1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have, for example, the set $B := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2} | b = a^2 + 5\}$, would it be wrong to say that, there is a bijection $h: (0,1) \to B \cap ((0,1) \times\mathbb{R})$ where $f(a) = a^2 + 5$. Thus, $B$ is uncountable. Is the reasoning here wrong?

I am having trouble figuring out how these kinds of problems are approached. Why is $(0,1)$ specifically used? Are there not other sets which are uncountable that one could use? Thanks!

Comment: @joeb I see. Why is $(0,1)$ so often used if $\mathbb{R}$ does the trick? Could you give me an example where using $(0,1)$ would be preferrable/necessary? Thanks.

Comment: One can show that there exists a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I find it easier (mechanically) to write a bijection with $(0,1)$ than with $\mathbb{R}$, but you could use either to establish that a set is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bijection $f:\{x:x \in \mathbb{R}, 0\le x \le 1\} \rightarrow B$ would prove $B$ is uncountable. We use $(0,1)$ often because it is uncountable and easy to use as the domain of functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the way I solved the problem in my post was unnecessarily complicated? What if my set had been something like ${(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}| y = e^x}$? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite know why you included the intersection with $(0,1) \times \mathbb{R}$, because if you did show that $h$ was a bijection, it would show $B \cap ((0,1) \times \mathbb{R})$ is uncountable, not (necessarily) that $B$ is uncountable. Also, what is the function $f$ you mention?

Comment: Also, do you have to use $(0,1)$ as the domain? It is often easier to do this like I mentioned, but in this case $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow B$ would probably be easier

Comment: Well, since $B \cap ((0,1) \times \mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $B$, wouldn't it make $B$ uncountable? Also, if my set is $R = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} | b = e^a \}$, could I simply say that there is a bijection $g: \mathbb{R} to B$? If so, wouldn't I have to prove that? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, if you know $S$ is uncountable and $S \subseteq R$, then you know $R$ is uncountable too; you're right so long as you wouldn't need to prove that as well. And yes, you need to define that bijection and show that it IS indeed a bijection.